# How user traffic is monitored in Django?

Tags: python, django, http

I'm trying to understand someone else's django code. There he used this line :

```
{# This information is cached and updated periodically via the context. 
#}
<div id="traffic">Traffic: {{ TRAFFIC }} users visited in the last 
hour</div>
```

I' not able to understand how it is working ?
Let me know if you need the views.py file.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just providing number of users who visited the website in the variable `TRAFFIC' from the view to the html code.

If you want to observe the traffic you can use Google Analytics, http://www.google.com/analytics/ or read the blog here https://www.augustash.com/our-blog/see-how-many-visitors-are-your-website-right-now